# How i set a pointer or flag to indicate that stop process inside Scrolling Field

Tags: livecode

I have an scrolling field i am try to implement replace the content on particular area but while replace the whole content are changed. How i set a pointer or flag to indicate that stop the replacement or stop the process. My code is

```
   on mouseUp
      put the htmlText of field "MytextField" into myHtml 
      set the caseSensitive to true 
      put the field SRText into myArrayToBe
      split myArrayToBe by CR
      put the number of lines of (the keys of myArrayToBe) into myArraylength
      repeat with i = 1 to myArraylength 
        put  myArrayToBe[i] into y
        split y by colon
        put y[1] into searchStr
        put y[2] into replaceStr
        if searchStr is empty then
          put the  0 into m 
        else 
          replace searchStr with "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" \
            & quote & ">" & searchStr & "</font></strike><font bgcolor=" \
            & quote & "green" & quote & ">" & replaceStr & "</font>" in myHtml    
        end if
      end repeat
      set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to myHtml
   end mouseUP
```

Comment: Again, you shouldn't use an array here. You should use the original list with `repeat for each line`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want or why, but here is an example that does what you ask for: replace strings in a particular area of a field.

```
on mouseUp
     put urlDecode("aaa+bbb+ccc+ddd+aaaa+ffff+gggg+aaaa+rrrr+dddd+ggg+dddd%0D%0Agggg+fff+eeeee+fff+ssss+ddd+aaaa+%0D%0Adddd+aaaa") into fld 1
     wait 30 ticks // so you can see that something happens
     lock screen
     select word 4 to 10 of fld 1
     replace "a" with "x" in the selection
     select empty
end mouseUp
```